# Android putExtra push data with same key from different buttons

Tags: java, android

I have a code that uses putextra method to push data from activity to another, I want to push different values using the same key
code:

```
String int_value = "int_value";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondScreen.class);
            intent.putExtra(int_value , 0);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondScreen.class);
            intent.putExtra(int_value , 1);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

And in the next activity:

```
int value;
String int_value = "int_value";

View myLayout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_screen);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int temp = intent.getIntExtra(int_value, value);


    myLayout = findViewById(R.id.myLayout);

    switch (value){

        case 0:
            myLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a);
            Log.e("VALUE" , String.valueOf(value));
            break;
        case 1:
            myLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.b);
            Log.e("VALUE" , String.valueOf(value));
            break;

    }
```

But the background always changes to a.jpg although I passed 0 & 1 (or a least I thought I did...)
what is the problem here?

Comment: `switch (temp)`

Answer (score 1):

just change value in switch to **temp**

```
switch ( temp){

    case 0:
        myLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a);
        Log.e("VALUE" , String.valueOf(value));
        break;
    case 1:
        myLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.b);
        Log.e("VALUE" , String.valueOf(value));
        break;

}
```

> because you are saving the value inside **temp**

```
int temp = intent.getIntExtra(int_value, value);
```